What is this part? Where can I purchase one? Elfa Classic(?) Rail Hook Clamp
I recently moved into an apartment with a wall-mounted rail hook system in a utility space. I believe the brand is "Elfa Classic".
There is one unattached hook about 12inches/30cm long. Presumably, this hook is supposed to mount onto the rail. However, it appears to be missing some kind of grey clamp with two screw holes.
Questions:

Can this hook be (re)attached to this rail?
If yes, what is this boxy grey part called? "Bracket" and "clamp" both seem to be specific Elfa parts, and I cannot find one on The Container Store not already attached to a hook.




Note: I am renting (so I am not looking to make drastic changes to the system) and the property owner is unfamiliar with this system.

So Google "Elfa Classic" purchase options... this question is not appropriate here.

I appreciate the RTFM/LMGTFY sentiment, but it was not as straightforward as you are thinking. Thanks though!

Not necessarily RTFM/LMGTFY... just trying to get you to an answer more quickly. "Shopping" questions are discouraged here but Google specializes in such. Congratulations on figuring it out!

Please contact the previous tenant for support.

Answered! https://www.containerstore.com/s/elfa/components/classic-by-elfa/elfa-utility-horizontal-bike-rack/123d?productId=10023224
The large hook slides into the smaller loop. This was not obvious to someone unfamiliar with these parts.

